# use javascript to insert google ads within a page of text

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I am trying to insert google ads after the first paragraph of the text box on my mediawiki site. My code is based on https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AdsWherever.

I have a function that returns a tag which will render the google ads code. 
I am using javascript to check if the tag is there, if it isn't I'm inserting it after the first paragraph.

The issue is none of the rest of the text in the text box is showing after the google ads. I think this may because the function is returning a value and breaking out of the code and so not allowing the rest of the javascript code to run. (I may be wrong but this is what I think the issue is).

How do I insert the google ads in the correct place and still show the text after the ads? 
I don't mind skipping the function altogether and just using javascript to insert the code but I don't know how to write the javascript so var b contains the javascript for the google ads.

This is my code:

```
$wgHooks['ParserFirstCallInit'][] = 'AdsSetup';
$wgHooks['EditPage::showEditForm:initial'][] = 'CheckHasTag';
function AdsSetup( &$parser ) {$parser->setHook( 'ads', 'AdsRender' ); return true;}
function AdsRender($input, $args ) {   
$input =""; $url = array(); global $wgOut;
$ad['goo1'] = '<html><br><script type="text/javascript">
        google_ad_client = "xxx";
        google_ad_width = 728;
        google_ad_height = 90;
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
        </script><br></html>';
$media = $args['media'];
return $ad[$media];
}

// check if content has <goo1> tag
function CheckHasTag($editPage){
global $wgOut;
$wgOut->addScript('<script type="text/javascript">
    var editTextboxText = document.getElementById("wpTextbox1").value;
                var searchFor = "goo1";
                var searchResult = editTextboxText.search(searchFor);
                if(searchResult == -1){
                var a = editTextboxText;
                var b = "\n<ads media=goo1>\n";
                var findP = "\n"; 
                var p = editTextboxText.search(findP);
                var position = p;
                document.getElementById("wpTextbox1").value = a.substr(0, position) + b + a.substr(position);
                }                   
</script>');
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var editTextboxText = document.getElementById("mw-content-text").innerHTML;
var searchFor = new RegExp("goo1");
if (searchFor.test(editTextboxText) === false) {

    var ad = document.createElement('ads');
    ad.setAttribute('media', 'goo1');
    var parent = document.getElementById("mw-content-text").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].parentNode;
    var secondParagraph = document.getElementById("mw-content-text").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].nextSibling;
    parent.insertBefore(ad, secondParagraph);
}
```

<kbd>[JSfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/ZZyU3/)</kbd>

Comment: I can't get this to work. Is there meant to be a line of code after this to output the result?

Comment: I've updated my [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pisi2012/ZZyU3/). The script is scoped in function now and you can start it with a click. The result is a red block in the text which you can inspect with Firebug/Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: I have the same start of the code as in the original question function but I added your code to CheckHasTag($editPage){function CheckHasTag($editPage){ global $wgOut;
$wgOut->addScript('<script type="text/javascript"> 
var editTextboxText = document.getElementById("wpTextbox1").innerHTML;
    var searchFor = new RegExp("goo1");
if (searchFor.test(editTextboxText) === false) {
var ad ...  parent.insertBefore(ad, secondParagraph);
 }}}</script>');return true;} However, the <ads media=goo1> is not showing. What am I missing?

Comment: Also - in mediawiki there is no <p> tag in the edit box. The linebreak is shown by "/n". However, I wrapped my code in <p> and it still didn't work...

Comment: I don't know the structure of your content and your linebreaks. A Paragraph is normally structured with a `<p>`-tag. If you got two `<p>`-areas, my code will insert an ad before the second `<p>`-area. Have you a URL to your content so i can see your structure?

Comment: I'm trying to insert the code into every page on my wiki. An example page is http://thepetwiki.com/EStahl/mw/index.php?title=Example_page

Comment: Is there a way to insert the google ads code as var b? And just ignore  the function AdsRender($input, $args ). Then my code will work fine. I just don't know how to make var b = "<script type="text/javascript">        google_ad_client = "xxx";...

Comment: Your content wrapper is "mw-content-text" and not "wpTextbox1" as in your question. I've updated my code and the fiddle. Copy and run it in your browser console. It will add an ad-tag to your content.